# Highest value of an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have an array with these values (returned from google.maps.LatLng):

```
var polygon = [
 { k=50.882917044569744, B=6.003985404968262}, 
 { k=50.88289589175401, B=6.003938466310501}, 
 { k=50.882934389871465, B=6.003895550966263}, 
 { k=50.88295554266969, B=6.003943160176277}
]
```

And I want the key of the one with the highest B value so in this case it would be `polygon[0]` I don't know how exactly the array is made actually but `console.log()` returns me this exactly:

```
[df { k=50.882917044569744, B=6.003985404968262, toString=function(), meer...}, df { k=50.88289589175401, B=6.003938466310501, toString=function(), meer...}, df { k=50.882934389871465, B=6.003895550966263, toString=function(), meer...}, df { k=50.88295554266969, B=6.003943160176277, toString=function(), meer...}]
```

And `polygon[0]` would return me the first object.

Comment: That's a syntax error; keys and values in a JavaScript object should be associated/assigned with `{keyName : keyValue}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always iterate the array with:

```
var polygon = [
    {k: 50.882917044569744, B: 6.003985404968262},
    {k: 50.88289589175401,  B: 6.003938466310501}, 
    {k: 50.882934389871465, B: 6.003895550966263},
    {k: 50.88295554266969,  B: 6.003943160176277}
];
var i, p;
for (i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++) {
    if (p === undefined || p.k < polygon[i].k) {
        p = polygon[i];
    }
}
console.log(p);
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! My goal was to get the top position of a polygon in google maps. All I needed to change was get the highest value of k instead of B but I managed to change that thanks a lot!

Comment: A better way would be to use a `LatLngBounds()` object, extend it by adding all paths of the polygon, and call the `.getBounds()` method.